# Wordpress - using meta_query between two small numbers

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I'm trying to use meta_query parmater to get posts with values between two values, the problem is it doesn't work for all the numbers.

This is work:

```
$array[] = array(
    'key' => 'd_weight',
    'value' => array(0,0.5),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
);
```

But for some reason this doesn't work:

```
$array[] = array(
    'key' => 'd_weight',
    'value' => array(0.1,0.5),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
);
```

The problem only occurs with numbers less than 1, on bigger number there is no problem...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: retrieve the meta value and do a comparison manually to verify it works

Comment: It works, even if I set the range to 0.000001-0.5 it doesn't work, but 0-0-.5 works great.

Comment: This would be much more helpful to others with this same question (me, for example) if you posted your full query code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For decimal numbers, you should use 'DECIMAL' in place of 'NUMERIC'

```
$array[] = array(
    'key' => 'd_weight',
    'value' => array(0.1,0.5),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'DECIMAL'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mridul's answer is partially correct, but there's more to it in the OP's case, specifically when dealing with the BETWEEN comparison. After changing from type=NUMERIC to type=DECIMAL, you also need special handling to filter the way WP typecasts to the DECIMAL datatype (otherwise it will use the default precision.) Very rough example below:

```
function wp_get_meta_sql_cast_decimal_precision($meta_query) {
    $meta_query['where'] = str_replace('DECIMAL', 'DECIMAL(10,3)', $meta_query['where']);
    return $meta_query;
}
add_filter('get_meta_sql', 'wp_get_meta_sql_cast_decimal_precision');
```